# RISC-V user level reference or reference implementation

Tags: riscv

Summary: What is the definitive reference or reference implementation for the RISC-V user-level ISA?

Context: The RISC-V website has "The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual" which explains the user-level instructions very well, but does not give an exact specification for them. I am trying to build a user-level ISA simulator now and intend to write an FPGA implementation later, so the exact behavior is important to me.

A reference implementation would be sufficient, but should preferably be as simple as possible -- i.e. I would try to understand a pipelined implementation only as a last resort. What *is* important is to have an understanding of the specified ISA and not of a single CPU implementation or compiler implementation.

One example to show my problem is the AUIPC instruction: The prose explanation says that "AUIPC forms a 32-bit offset from the 20-bit U-immediate, filling in the lowest 12 bits with zeros, adds this offset to the pc, then places the result in register rd." I wanted to know whether this refers to the old or new PC, i.e. the position of the AUIPC instruction or the next instruction. I looked at the "RISCV Angel" implementation, but that seems to mask out the lower bits of the (old) PC -- not just of the immediate -- which I could not find any reason for in the spec, not even in the change history of the spec (since Angel is a bit older). Instead of an answer, I now have two questions about AUIPC. Many other instructions pose similar problems to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT the RISC-V Instruction Set Manual you cite is the closest thing there is to a definitive reference.  If there are things that are unclear or incorrect in there then you could open issues at the Github site where that document is maintained: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual

As far as AIUPC is concerned, the answer is implied, but not stated explicitly, by this sentence at the bottom of page 9 in the current manual:

> There is one additional user-visible register: the program counter **pc** holds the address of the current instruction.

Based on that statement I would expect that the **pc** value that is seen and manipulated by the AIUPC instruction is the address of the AIUPC instruction itself.

This interpretation is supported by the discussion of the JALR instruction:

> The indirect jump instruction JALR (jump and link register) uses the I-type encoding.  The target address is obtained by adding the 12-bit signed I-immediate to the register *rs1*, then setting the least-signicant bit of the result to zero.  The address of the instruction following the jump (**pc**+4) is written to register *rd*.

Given that the address of the following instruction is expressed as **pc**+4, it seems clear that the **pc** value visible during the execution of JALR is the address of the JALR instruction itself.

The latest draft of the manual (at https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/draft-20190321-ba17106/riscv-spec.pdf) makes the situation slightly clearer.  In place of this in the current manual:

> AUIPC appends 12 low-order zero bits to the 20-bit U-immediate, sign-extends the result to 64 bits, then adds it to the **pc** and places the result in register *rd*.

the latest draft says:

> AUIPC forms a 32-bit offset from the 20-bit U-immediate, filling in the lowest 12 bits with zeros, adds this offset to the **pc** of the AUIPC instruction, then places the result in register *rd*.

Comment: This seems implausible to me since the ISA is already used as a contract between multiple compilers and multiple implementations, some even in silicon. This would not be possible if there was disagreement about such issues, and a silicon implementor would not base his (expensive) work on guessing what an instruction does. OTOH, if a silicon implementor looks at compiler output, there is the risk of interpreting a compiler bug as a property of the specification.

Comment: I agree it would make no sense for implementers, especially hardware implementers, to be guessing or disagreeing.  Presumably they would seek and obtain clarification before proceeding. Those clarifications might not have made it into the Manual yet.  It wouldn't be the first time that a piece of documentation seemed clear to the people who were working on the project but was ambiguous to others.  If you're finding ambiguities then you could try opening issues at https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/issues  The team there seems pretty responsive.

Comment: I agree that the manual / official spec should contain these answers, so regardless of whether there are other sources used by implementors I'll open tickets there.

Comment: As you said, the clarifications have been added quickly by the spec team, so I'll consider your answer the "right" one to my question.